How to log Python exceptions to a file implicitly?
I am wondering if there is a mechanism to write Python exceptions to a log file without explicitly calling log.exception("oh!") in a try-except-block?
e.g. in this snippet I show two cases:
import logging
log = logging.getLogger("myLogger")

foo = 1/0 # case 1: this sure fires an exception which I want to see written to a log file

try:
    bar = 1/0
except:
    pass
    # case 2: is it necessary to explicitly put a `log.exception("<placeholder error message>")` here?

In my program I'd like to collect information about exceptions that have been thrown, when it was used by colleagues so I can help them, so there is a gap between run time and time for examination.
I am using log.info and log.warning, but I have not used log.exception in exception handling so far. So is there a good way to do this implicitly instead of explicitly or would that be an anti-pattern?
